# conversion - SQL to LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

How can the following be accomplished using `LINQ`

```
SELECT r.BrandID 
FROM dbo.Items AS r
JOIN Brands AS d ON r.BrandID = d.BrandID
WHERE CategoryID IN (SELECT CategoryID 
                     FROM dbo.Categories
                     WHERE Name = 'Bread - Bakery')
```

Code for `Brand` class:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Brand Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Code for `Item` class:

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
}
```

code for `Category` class:

```
public class Category
{
    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Category Name")]
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please do help us by editing your question and add a simplified version that contains the relevant parts of the classes you use. Please do add your requirement, instead of us trying to extract the requirement from your SQL code. By the way: what did you try already? What was wrong with your results?

Comment: I'm new to `LINQ` .. reading tutorials.

Comment: Note that you don't need `JOIN Brands AS d ON r.BrandID = d.BrandID`. You can select `d.BrandID`. Also: it's always important to know which type of data access you're in. I guess Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dbContext.Items
  .Where(x => x.Category.Name.Equals("Bread - Bakery"))
  .Select(x => x.BrandID);
```

I am not sure why you need to use below join. It seems that it is not needed (unless intentionally inner joined with brands to remove non-matching records from items)

```
JOIN Brands AS d ON r.BrandID = d.BrandID
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, pity you didn't write your requirements, now I have to guess what they are from your SQL code.

So you have a database with `Brands`, `Items` and `Categories`. Every `Item` has a `Category`, every `Category` can be used by zero or more `Items`: a one-to-many relation

Every `Item` is of a certain `Brand`, Every `Brand` can have zero or more items: also a straightforward one-to-many relation.

Finally every `Brand` has zero or more `Categories`, every `Category` has zero or more `Brands`: many-to-many

Now you take your collection of `Items`, you only want to keep those `Items` that have a Category with a `Name` that equals `Bread - Bakery`. From the remaining items you want all their BrandIds.

The requirement would be: "Give me the `BrandIds` of all `Items` that have a `Category` with a `Name` that equals 'Bread - Bakery`.

If you use entity framework, it is usually easier if you use the `virtual ICollection` instead of doing the join yourself. Entity framework knows the relations between the tables and will compose the proper joins for it.

```
var result = myDbContext.Items                             // from the collection of Items
    .Where(item => item.Category.Name == "Bread - Bakery") // keep only those with a Category
                                                           // that has a Name equal to ...
    .Select(item.BrandId);                        // from the remaining items select the BrandId
```

If you really want, and you can convince your project leader that entity framework can't be trusted to do the proper joins you can do the join yourself:

```
// get the sequence of categories that I'm interested in:
var breadBakeryCategories = myDbContext.Categories
    .Where(category => category.Name == "Bread - Bakery");

// join the items with these categories
// and select the BrandIds
var requestedBrandIds= myDbContext.Items
    .Join(breadBakeryCategories,
    item => item.CategoryId,           // from every Item take the CategoryId,
    category => category.CategoryId,   // from every Category take the CategoryId
    (item, category) => item.BrandId);   // when they match, select the BrandId
```

TODO: consider concatenating this into one big ugly LINQ statement.

**Remark 1**

You do realize that your result might have the same BrandIds several times, don't you?

If you don't want that, start with the Brands:

```
var result = myDbContext.Brands
.Where(brand => brand.Items.Select(item => item.Category.Name)
                .Where(name => name == "Bread - Bakery")
                .Any())
.Select(brand => brand.brandId);
```

In words: from the collection of Brands, keep only those Brands that have at least one Category with a name equal to "Bread - Bakery". From the remaining Brands select the BrandId.

** Remark 2 **

Why are your one-to-many Lists instead of ICollections? Are you sure that `brand.Categories[4]` has a proper meaning?

```
var result = myDbContext.Brands
    .Where(brand => brand.Category[4].Name == "Bread - Bakeries");
```

Your compiler won't complain, but you'll get runtime errors.

Consider using `virtual ICollection<...>` for your one-to-many and many-to-many relations. This way you'll have exactly the functionality you expect with a database table, and your compiler will complain if you try to use functionality that can't be translated into SQL